# While accessing data from a [ JSON file ] it shows undefined In react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a `JSON`  file  named data.json which contains the following data.

```
 {
  "nav": [
    "computer engineering",
    "civl engineering ",
    "electrical engineering "
  ],
  "subjects": {
    "computer engineering": {
      "semester 1": [
        "Engineering physics-I",
        "Engineering Chemistry-I",
        "Engineering Mathematics-I",
        "Computer Fundamental",
        "Communication Nepali",
        "Communication English",
        "Computer programming in c",
        "Engineering drawing "
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And when i access the data from the console it gives the proper output,
and when i try to access it using the following  code it gives undefined.

```
import React from "react";
import { Context } from "../Context";
import data from "../data.json"; 

  const { click, semdata } = React.useContext(Context);
  const [semesterData, setSemesterData] = semdata;
  name = "computer engineering";
```

> update
>
> ```
>  {semesterData ? console.log(semesterData) : null}
>   { semesterData ? console.log(name) : null }
> ```

```
 {semesterData ? console.log(data.subjects[name][semesterData]) : null}
```

[image: The Result when I try in console window.]

[image: The Result when I try the application .]

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `semesterData` has the wrong value. It's hard to tell, you haven't provided a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin The `semesterData` has the correct value i will try to make the question more minimal and clear thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't give the proper output is because you are logging to the console in the ternary instead of rendering it to JSX.

```js
 {semesterData ? data.subjects[name][semesterData]) : null}
```

This way it will be rendered if the ternary returns `true`.

Comment: Thank you but I first tried to map the data and got an error cannot map undefined so, I am  trying to figure out how it is getting undefined.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce your error in a REPL like for example CodeSandbox? I was unable to reproduce your error so it would help a lot with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about data.json, I think the way that you used `useContext` was wrong.

It's a simple example that shows how to use `useContext`

```
import React from "react";
const data = {
  nav: ["computer engineering", "civl engineering ", "electrical engineering "],
  subjects: {
    "computer engineering": {
      "semester 1": [
        "Engineering physics-I",
        "Engineering Chemistry-I",
        "Engineering Mathematics-I",
        "Computer Fundamental",
        "Communication Nepali",
        "Communication English",
        "Computer programming in c",
        "Engineering drawing "
      ]
    }
  }
};
const Context = React.createContext();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ semdata: "semester 1" }}>
      <div className="App">
        <Display />
      </div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
const Display=()=> {
  const { semdata } = React.useContext(Context);
  const [semesterData, setSemesterData] = React.useState(semdata);
  const name = "computer engineering";
  return <div>{semesterData ? data.subjects[name][semesterData] : ""}</div>;
}
```